# Canvas draw multiple path in once time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working with canvas to draw route.
I'm facing with big issue when try to draw multiple path once time.

Scenario will be:

- User 1 go from A -> B -> C (6 seconds)
- User 2 go from A -> C -> D (6 seconds)

When I tick to User 1 and User 2, my canvas with draw both user separately (async). In 6 second the route must be display for both users.

I use timeout to set time draw from position to position. If only tick to 1 user only, my code will correctly but if 2 or above users, my code have problems.

```
doLineDraw = function(points, color) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.strokeStyle = color;
            animatedBSpline(vm.context,points);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
```

Because I spend 2 seconds to draw path1 from point1 to point2 but at that time, I also draw for user2 path2 from point1 to point 3 so the path1 is not completed but path 2 has begin. My code will draw not correctly.

Please give me advice about it.

Comment: how does it take 2 seconds to draw a path? did you artificially delay it? can you show the code for that?

Comment: I only set timeout for the drawing, in drawing I separate to multi line shorter